# Is there a java library that supports smart parameter expansion, String.format, and more

Tags: java, logging

Here's what I'm looking for:

- Java
- Log library that could replace commons logging or slf4j
- Parameter expansion only when log level requires it (i.e. no `if (log.isDebugEnabled())` blocks)
- String formatting the same as `java.lang.String.format`
- Detect java.lang.Throwable as final parameter and log stack trace

The goal is to write code like this

```
private static final Log log = new Log.getLog(MyClass.class);
// ...
String value = "test";
log.debug("The value is [%s]", value); // [1]
// ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Caught Exception: %s", e.getMessage(), e); // [2]
}
```

[1] would print a log statement like

```
The value is [test]
```

If the log level were `INFO`, the string format operation would not happen.

[2] would print

```
Caught Exception: [value of e.getMessage()]
java.lang.Exception
  at com.my.org.MyClass.myMethod(MyClass.[line number])
  at [...]
```

This seems like pretty sane behavior to me. I'm surprised I can't easily find a library that does this.

EDIT: I should have specified, but slf4j does not meet all these requirements.

Comment: AFAIK, parameter expansion or evaluation on use is not possible in Java. Any expression argument (e.g. `obj.toString()`) passed to a method has to be first evaluated beforehand. Many frameworks (notably sl4j) provide a neat trick by accepting `Object` instead of `String` so the `obj.toString()` is only done when it is required. Other than that, tough luck. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBoss has a [logging implementation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/solder/latest/api/org/jboss/logging/Logger.html) that does printf- and MessageFormat-style formatting. Supposedly it can be used on it's own, but I can't find a project for it, other than its integration with Seam Solder. There are standalone artifacts though: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/

Answer (score 7):

> Java

SLF4J with Logback binding.

> Log library that could replace commons logging or slf4j

The only well established alternatives are Log4J and `java.util.logging`...

> Parameter expansion only when log level requires it (i.e. no if (log.isDebugEnabled()) blocks)

In SLF4J if you type:

```
log.debug("Names are: {}", namesCollection);
```

Then costly `toString()` will only be executed if `isDebugEnabled()` returns true (no need to provide it explicitly).

> String formatting the same as java.lang.String.format

Do you really need fancy formatting (decimals, currencies, locales) in log files? Or is `{}` lazy expansion enough (see above)?

> Detect java.lang.Throwable as final parameter and log stack trace

SLF4J works this way [since 1.6](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#paramException).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm currently using slf4j. It doesn't meet all my requirements (namely String.format formatting).

Comment: @three_cups_of_java, what does `%d`, `%f`, `%s` buy you that `{}` doesn't? The only think I can think of is if you wanted to do something like %2.2f. But honestly, your logs should be formatted like a business report, you're going to want raw output.

Comment: @TimBender, does it really matter what it buys for me? The question was asking for a logging library that expanded parameters the same as `String.format`.

Comment: @three_cups_of_java, if you don't have a rational reason for your requirement, then you might want to reconsider the requirement. Anyway, Mac gave an answer that meets your requirements.

Comment: @TimBender, my only point was that you seemed to be saying that an answer that does not meet my requirements should be sufficient because you couldn't think of a reason why my requirements/question are valid. I agree in general that what slf4j offers is really close and should most project's logging requirements. Unfortunately, I don't always control all of my environment/requirements, so I can't really defend my need for this, except to say that it is a requirement.